# How to join two tables and fetch three columns by join query in laravel..As i m new to laravel i m facing problem while doing this

Tags: database, join, eloquent, laravel-8

It is my controller

$courses = Assigncourse::join('teachers', 'teachers.id', '=', 'assigncourses.teacher_id')
->join('courses', 'courses.id', '=', 'assigncourses.course2')
->where('teachers.id', '=', $id)
->get(['teachers.name','courses.id', 'courses.course_title','courses.course_code','courses.course_credit', 'courses.course_type']);

[My database:I am trying to fetch these couse1,course2 and course3 individually.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMsWM.png)

[Courses database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V71vT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You Should learn eloquent Relationship No need for Join Query
> In Your **AssignCourse.php Model File** Make function

```
 public function teachers()
    {
        $this->belongsToMany(Teacher::class,'teacher_id','id');
    }

  public function courses()
  {
    $this->belongsToMany(Course::class,'course2','id');
  }
```

> So you can get the teachers table data in your **Controller** by calling with function

```
$assignCourses = Assigncourse::with(['teachers','courses'])->get(); 
dd($assignCourses);
```

> Hope this Helps

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I'm still getting some erorr..can we discuss on telegram or somewhere else?